# Unable to fix error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375/. Is the docker daemon running? for remote GitLab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I am struggling to resolve the issue

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375/. Is the docker daemon running?

I am using our companies GitLab EE instance, which comes with a bunch of shared group runners. However I would like to be able to use my own runners especially since I will be able to employ the GPU for some machine learning tasks. I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
run_tests:
  image: python:3.9-slim-buster
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install make
  script:
    - python --version
    - pip --version
    - make test

build_image:
  image: docker:20.10.23
  services:
    - docker:20.10.23-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CRETDIR: "/certs"
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
  before_script:
    - echo "User    $REGISTRY_USER"
    - echo "Token   $ACCESS_TOKEN"
    - echo "Host    $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL"
    - echo "$ACCESS_TOKEN" | docker login --username $REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL
  script:
    - docker build --tag $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL/<PATH_TO_USER>/python-demoapp .
    - docker push $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL/<PATH_TO_USER>/python-demoapp
```

The application is currently a demo and it's used in the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP8kir2GUgo). Note that `<PATH_TO_USER>` in the above URLs is just a placeholder (I cannot reveal the original one since it contains internal information) and points at my account space, where the project `python-demoapp` is located. With untagged jobs enabled, I am hoping to have the following workflow:

1. Push application code change
2. GitLab pipeline triggered

   2.1 Execute tests

   2.2 Build image

   2.3 Push image to container repository
3. Re-use image with application inside (e.g. run locally)

I have setup the variables accordingly to contain my username, an access token (generated in GitLab) and the registry host. All of these are correct and I am able to execute everything up to the `docker build ...` section.

Now as for the runner I followed the instructions provided in GitLab to set it up. I chose to create a VM (QEMU+KVM+libvirt) with a standard minimal installation of Debian 11 with everything set to default (including NAT network, which appears to be working since I can access the Internet through it), where the runner currently resides. I am doing this in order to save the setup and later on transfer it onto a server and run multiple instances of the VM with slight modification (e.g. GPU passthrough for Nvidia CUDA Docker/Podman setup).

Beside the runner (binary was downloaded from our GitLab instance), I installed Docker CE (in the future will be replaced with Podman due to licensing and pricing) following the [official instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/). The Docker executor is ran as a `systemd` service (`docker.service`, `docker.socket`), that is I need `sudo` to interact with it. The runner has its own user (also part of the `sudo` group) as the official documentation is telling me to do.

The GitLab runner's configuration file `gitlab-runner-config.toml` contains the following information:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Test runner (Debian 11 VM, Docker CE, personal computer)"
  url = "<COMPANY_GITLAB_INSTANCE_URL>"
  id = <RUNNER_ID>
  token = "<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-01-24T09:18:33Z
  token_expeires_at = 2023-02-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3.9-slim-buster"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    cache_dir = "/cache"
    volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client", "/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
```

The configuration file was generated by running

```
sudo gitlab-runner register --url <COMPANY_GITLAB_INSTANCE_URL> --registration-token <ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I added the extra cache volumes beside `/cache`, the `cache_dir` and changed `priveleged to` true` (based on my research). All for this based on various posts (including Docker's own issue tracking system) from people having the same issue.

I have made sure that `dockerd` is listening on the respective port (see comment below for the original poster):

```
$ sudo ss -nltp
State       Recv-Q     Send-Q       Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port         Process
LISTEN      0          128                  0.0.0.0:22      0.0.0.0:*                 users:(("sshd",pid=601,fd=3))
LISTEN      0          128                     [::]:22      [::]:*                    users:(("sshd",pid=601,fd=4))
LISTEN      0          4096                     *:2375         *:*                    users:(("dockerd",pid=618,fd=9))
```

In addition I have added `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` to the `.bashrc` of ever user out there (except root - perhaps that's the problem?) including the `gitlab-runner` user.

The `Dockerfile` within the repository contains the following:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
```

The log file from the CICD pipeline for this job is (trimmed down) as follows:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.0 (12335144)
  on Test runner (Debian 11 VM, Docker CE, personal computer) <IDENTIFIER>, system ID: <SYSTEM_ID>
Preparing the "docker" executor 02:34
Using Docker executor with image docker:20.10.23 ...
Starting service docker:20.10.23-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:20.10.23-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:70ae571e74c1d711d3d5bf6f47eaaf6a51dd260fe0036c7d6894c008e7d24297 for docker:20.10.23-dind with digest docker@sha256:85a1b877d0f59fd6c7eebaff67436e26f460347a79229cf054dbbe8d5ae9f936 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
*** WARNING: Service runner-dbms-tss-project-42787-concurrent-0-b0bbcfd1a821fc06-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-dbms-tss-project-42787-concurrent-0-b0bbcfd1a821fc06-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2023-01-26T10:09:30.933962365Z Certificate request self-signature ok
2023-01-26T10:09:30.933981575Z subject=CN = docker:dind server
2023-01-26T10:09:30.943472545Z /certs/server/cert.pem: OK
2023-01-26T10:09:32.607191653Z Certificate request self-signature ok
2023-01-26T10:09:32.607205915Z subject=CN = docker:dind client
2023-01-26T10:09:32.616426179Z /certs/client/cert.pem: OK
2023-01-26T10:09:32.705354066Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.705227099Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.706355355Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.706298649Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.707357671Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.707318325Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=72
2023-01-26T10:09:32.707460567Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.707425103Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.707466043Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.707433214Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.707468621Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.707445818Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.707491420Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.707459517Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.768123834Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32Z" level=warning msg="containerd config version `1` has been deprecated and will be removed in containerd v2.0, please switch to version `2`, see https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/PLUGINS.md#version-header"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.768761837Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.768714616Z" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=5b842e528e99d4d4c1686467debf2bd4b88ecd86 version=v1.6.15
2023-01-26T10:09:32.775684382Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.775633270Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.775764839Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.775729470Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.779824244Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.779733556Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"ip: can't find device 'aufs'\\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.779836825Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.779790644Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.779932891Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.779904447Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (ext4) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.779944348Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.779929392Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.779958443Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.779940747Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.779963141Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.779951447Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.780022382Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.780000266Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.780134525Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.780107812Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.780499276Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.780466045Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.780507315Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.780489797Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.780548237Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.780529316Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.780552144Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.780544232Z" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
2023-01-26T10:09:32.795982271Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795854170Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.795991535Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795882407Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.exchange\"..." type=io.containerd.event.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.795993243Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795894367Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.795994639Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795932065Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.795996061Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795949931Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.795997456Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795963627Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.content-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796001074Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.795983562Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796219139Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796194319Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.images-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796231068Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796216520Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796240878Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796228403Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796254974Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796239993Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796261567Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796252251Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796385360Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796360610Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
2023-01-26T10:09:32.796451372Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796435082Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups\"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797042788Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.796984264Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797093357Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797073997Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797100437Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797091084Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.restart\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797148696Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797138286Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797164876Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797153186Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797176732Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797165488Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797187328Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797176464Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.events\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797208889Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797196407Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797220812Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797209290Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.images\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797232031Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797221051Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797242686Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797231676Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797254415Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797243815Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.opt\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797484534Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797456547Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797500729Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797487444Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797524336Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797502098Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.version\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797535447Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797526933Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797562995Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797539848Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797570791Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797558864Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797589770Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797579849Z" level=error msg="failed to initialize a tracing processor \"otlp\"" error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797766243Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797741256Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797805542Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797792483Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797836935Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797820296Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock
2023-01-26T10:09:32.797854712Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.797842891Z" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.029983s"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.802286356Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.802232926Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.802291484Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.802269035Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.802322916Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.802306355Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.802369464Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.802323232Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.803417318Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.803366010Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.803424723Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.803376046Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.803426453Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.803384392Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.803428210Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.803389450Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
2023-01-26T10:09:32.837720263Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.837658881Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
2023-01-26T10:09:32.886897024Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.886828923Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.18.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.920867085Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.920800006Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
2023-01-26T10:09:32.944768798Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.944696558Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=6051f14 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.23
2023-01-26T10:09:32.944804324Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.944774928Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.973804146Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.973688991Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
2023-01-26T10:09:32.976059008Z time="2023-01-26T10:09:32.975992051Z" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2376"
*********
Pulling docker image docker:20.10.23 ...
Using docker image sha256:25deb61ef2709b05249ad4e66f949fd572fb43d67805d5ea66fe3f86766b5cef for docker:20.10.23 with digest docker@sha256:2655039c6abfc8a1d75978c5258fccd5c5cedf880b6cfc72077f076d0672c70a ...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on runner-dbms-tss-project-42787-concurrent-0 via debian...
Getting source from Git repository 00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/<PATH_TO_USER>/python-demoapp/.git/
Checking out 93e494ea as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:25deb61ef2709b05249ad4e66f949fd572fb43d67805d5ea66fe3f86766b5cef for docker:20.10.23 with digest docker@sha256:2655039c6abfc8a1d75978c5258fccd5c5cedf880b6cfc72077f076d0672c70a ...
$ echo "User    $REGISTRY_USER"
User    [MASKED]
$ echo "Token   $ACCESS_TOKEN"
Token   [MASKED]
$ echo "Host    $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL"
Host    ..............
$ echo "$ACCESS_TOKEN" | docker login --username $REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ docker build --tag $REGISTRY_HOST_ALL/<PATH_TO_USER>/python-demoapp .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375/. Is the docker daemon running?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

From my understanding I need two images here:

- The `python`-capable one - here the official Python image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), which is used to run the tests as well as for the image that is added to the container registry
- The Docker DinD one - this is the Docker in Docker setup, which allows building a Docker image inside a running Docker container.

The second one is way above my head and it's the (for me) obvious culprit for my headaches.

Perhaps important additional information: my computer is outside our company's network. The GitLab instance is accessible externally through user authentification (username + password for the WebUI, access tokens and SSH keys otherwise).

Do I need two separate runners? I have seen a lot of examples, where people are using a single runner to do multiple jobs including testing and image building (even packaging) so I don't believe I do. I am not really a Docker expert as you can probably tell. :D If more information is required, please let me know in the comments below, especially if I am overdoing it and there is a much easier way to accomplish what I am trying to.

---

**DISCUSSION**

**Health check error regarding Docker volume**

I can see the following error in the log posted above:

```
Health check error:
service "runner-dbms-tss-project-42787-concurrent-0-b0bbcfd1a821fc06-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
```

The footprint looked familiar so I went back to check some old commands I executed and apparently this is a Docker volume. However on my host

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER
local      runner-...415a70
local      runner-...66cea8
```

neither volumes have that name. So I am guessing that this is a volume that is created by Docker in Docker.

**Adding hosts to JSON configuration file for Docker daemon**

I added the following configuration at `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/90-docker.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --config-file /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

with `daemon.json` containing the following:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375",
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  ]
}
```

Now I am noticing an additional error in the job's log:

```
failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: is a directory
```

On my host I checked and the path is an actual socket file (information retrieved by executing `file` command on the path). This means that the issues is again inside the Docker container, that is part of the DinD. I have read online that apparently Docker would automatically create the path and it will be a directory for some reason.

In addition the above mentioned error in the original question has now changed to

```
unable to resolve docker endpoint: Invalid bind address format: http://localhost:2375/
```

even though I cannot find any `http://localhost:2375` entry on my host, leading again to the conclusion that something with the DinD setup went wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that docker listen on `2375`? maybe docker is running on another port like `2376`. please run `ss -nltp` to make sure about docker is running on which port.

Comment: I am sure it's listening on this port. The output of `ss` also shows that. I will update my post to provide this information. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @rbaleksandar, Have you managed to fix this issue?